# Refresh tab after switching tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In server function I have

this function computes SalesClientData dataframe using noc and endDate input which are taken from selectInput and dateInput controls

The result of this function is used to plot output on tab 1

```
    getPlotData <- reactive({

      req(input$noc, input$endDate)

      inpParam <<- input$noc 
      getSalesData(inpParam)
      End_date <<- input$endDate    

      SalesClientData <<- "a"

  })
```

I have another function which is not dependent on any input but generates output table but this function changes the value of SalesClientData to b and when I move to tab 1 again the value of SalesClientData is still b instead of a

The result of this function is used to plot output on tab 2

```
 getFinalReportData <- reactive({

    getInpChoice()
    SalesClientData <<- "b"

  })
```

What I want to do is after move back to tab 1 the value should change to a of SalesClientData

I have used value a and b for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input$tabs` to [access the active tab name](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html#know-which-tab-is-currently-visible). To implement this, you could use:

```r
observeEvent(input$tabs,{
  if(input$tabs == "tab1") {
    SalesClientData <<- "a"
  } else {
    SalesClientData <<- "b"
  }
})
```

I feel that there may be a more optimal solution to your problem than an `if` statement, but with your sample info this is the best I can come up with. Your use of the global `<<-` operator to assign values inside a `reactive()` function is counter to what reactive functions should be used for, and the use of `<<-` often has [undesirable effects](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#binding). `reactive()` should return a value/object that is used elsewhere in your application. `observe()` is used when you want to modify an object without returning anything, which is why I used `observe()` in my answer (You wish to modify `SalesClientData` in the environment without returning anything).

I would review the documentation for reactivity:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html 
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactivity.html